# Natural derivative of Vector Fields on manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I'm learning about connections and my book says that there is no natural derivative for a vector field on a manifold. Wouldn't it be possible to cook up a connection by just letting $\nabla_{v_p}X = \sum v_pa^i \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}|_p$ where $\sum a^i \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}|_p$ is the coordinate representation of $X$ about $p$ or do we run into the problem that this is dependent on the choice of coordinates? Apparently we are able to do this in $R^n$ but this is not the case for a general manifold? Thank you.

Comment: Does $v_p a^i$ denote the directional derivative of $a^i$ w.r.t. $v_p$? If so, then yes, the resulting expression depends on a choice of coordinates, so like you say, this construction only gives a "natural" derivative when one has preferred coordinates on the manifold.

Comment: So is the point that in different coordinate systems you would get a different vector? Wouldn't we run into a similar complication with out definition in $R^n$ if we switch from our coordinate system to another?

Comment: right you have to show that your definition is compatible between different coordinate patches and it is impossible in general cases.

Comment: @Selfstudier Yes, or put another way, if we use coordinates $(x^a)$ on $\Bbb R^n$ other than the standard ones, the formula for the standard connection (the Euclidean directional derivative) is not the one given in the question. It's a good exercise to compute the Euclidean directional derivative in, e.g., polar coordinates $(r, \theta)$.

Comment: Maybe think about it this way: The reason we can use this simple procedure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is because the standard coordinate system is global. We can take any vector field on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and express it in terms of the standard coordinates, then use the directional derivative on the components to define a connection. On a general manifold, we can do this procedure in a coordinate chart, but then this only defines a $\textit{local}$ connection, that is, this connection only operates on vector fields defined on the coordinate chart. We can do this local construction on 2 different charts...

Comment: ...but then there's no reason to expect that they would agree at points in the overlap of the 2 charts. The definition of a connection bypasses this issue of trying to do things locally chart-by-chart and making things agree, and instead starts with a global object so that we know a priori that the local expressions will agree upon change of coordinates.